# Turn off Toad word wrapping in output table

Tags: toad

I have a table with a field which contains lots of XML data and that data comes back in multiple lines causing it to be difficult to scroll through.

I have only been able to figure out how to turn off the wrapping in the editor, but not the output table. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot or explain in more detail what you're seeing? I tested with a table having a very long string in one of the records (4000 chars). When I execute using F9 the grid shows the data on a single line. When I execute using F5 the data is wrapped and shown as you'd see when executing using SQL*Plus.

Comment: @MichaelS. this is the answer. I was executing as a script and that is why I was seeing the wrapped data.

Comment: There are many SQL*Plus commands for formatting your output. Read the docs and search on StackOverflow, etc. My knowledge is limited here, but you might find a format you prefer. For single statement execution my preferred method is to use F9, reserving F5 for true scripts.